# add link on facebook cover photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to add main company facebook page url on it chain or group of business companies cover photo page. 
For example.[Starbucks (1500 Broadway, New York)](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Starbucks/142792602424398?ref=ts&fref=ts) add Main [Starbucks](https://www.facebook.com/Starbucks) Page on its cover page. How can it be done? What is this feature called?

Pls check sceenshot.

[image]

Comment: That”s a feature called [“Global Pages”](https://www.facebook-studio.com/news/item/announcing-a-new-pages-structure-for-global-brands). But I think you have to spend a certain amount on advertising to be able to use that.

Comment: Thank CBore, I can report my client about these feature, as your help.

Comment: To add on to CBroe, this feature is also referred to as **Page Locations**.  Each location is a Facebook Page with a single parent Facebook Page  that is the main brand. This is useful for Pages that have multiple retail locations where it's useful to have a Page for each store.